# Difference between AからBで and AからBまで

Tags: grammar, particle-で, reading-comprehension, particle-まで

> 台風が近くに来ると、**沖縄県から本州の広い場所で**、とても強い雨がたくさん降る心配があります。
>   If the typhoon comes near then, **from Okinawa to the wide place of Honshuu**, there is a worry that there will be a lot of very strong rainfall.

I'm not convinced about my translation of the bold part. What on earth is 本州の広い場所?

I've also noticed a few times in reading the NHK easy news that they write AからBで where I would have expected to see AからB**ま**で. Am I wrong to think this should be まで? What is the difference between the two constructs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are parsing the sentence incorrectly:

The first part is: 沖縄県{おきなわけん}から本州{ほんしゅう}（まで）の //
second part: 広{ひろ}い場所{ばしょ}で

Translation: 
from Okinawa prefecture to Honshuu //
in a wide area

Putting it together, the full translation would thus be:
As the typhoon approaches, there is a worry that there will be a lot of heavy rain **in a wide area from Okinawa prefecture to Honshuu**

Answer (score 2):

> OP: (1) 沖縄県から本州の広い場所で
>   bjorn: (2) 沖縄県から本州（まで）の // 広い場所で

bjornさんの回答｛かいとう｝は大変｛たいへん｝良｛よ｝い（+1）と思｛おも｝います。

bjornさんの回答に加｛くわ｝えて、(1)をもとにいくつか応用｛おうよう｝例文｛れいぶん｝を示｛しめ｝します。

- (1)では「広い**場所**で」となっていますが、「広い**範囲{はんい}** で」という表現｛ひょうげん｝も良く使｛つか｝われます。むしろ「広い範囲で」の方が一般的｛いっぱんてき｝だと思｛おも｝います。
  (3) 沖縄県から本州の**範囲**で
  (4) 沖縄県から本州までの**範囲**で
  (5) 沖縄県から本州の広い**範囲**で
  (6) 沖縄県から本州までの広い**範囲**で
- 「範囲で」の代｛か｝わりに「範囲**内｛ない｝** で」とも表現されます。しかし、(1)の「場所で」の代わりに「場所**内**で」とは言｛い｝いません。
  <del>(7) 沖縄県から本州の場所**内**で</del>
  <del>(8) 沖縄県から本州までの場所**内**で</del>
  <del>(9) 沖縄県から本州の広い場所**内**で</del>
  <del>(10) 沖縄県から本州までの広い場所**内**で</del>
  (11) 沖縄県から本州の範囲**内**で
  (12) 沖縄県から本州までの範囲**内**で
  (13) 沖縄県から本州の広い範囲**内**で
  (14) 沖縄県から本州までの広い範囲内で
- 台風と違｛ちが｝って竜巻｛たつまき｝のように非常｛ひじょう｝に狭｛せま｝い範囲で被害｛ひがい｝が発生｛はっせい｝する場合｛ばあい｝には、「広い」の代わりに「**狭い**」が用｛もち｝いられます。
  (15) この度｛たび｝の竜巻ではＡ町｛ちょう｝から隣｛となり｝のＢ町の**狭い**範囲で被害｛ひがい｝があった。
  (16) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの**狭い**範囲で被害があった。
  (17) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町の**狭い**範囲内で被害があった。
  (18) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの**狭い**範囲内で被害があった。
- 非常に狭い範囲を強調｛きょうちょう｝する場合｛ばあい｝には、いろいろな表現があります。
  (19) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの**非常に**狭い範囲で被害があった。
  (20) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの**非常に**狭い範囲内で被害があった。
  (21) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの**ごく**狭い範囲で被害があった。
  (22) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの**ごく**狭い範囲内で被害があった。
  (23) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの狭い範囲に**限{かぎ}って**被害があった。
  (24) この度の竜巻ではＡ町から隣のＢ町までの狭い範囲内に**限{かぎ}って**被害があった。

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think they would use まで to describe the course of typhoon rather than using で to describe the coverage of typhoon.
If I see this image, from Osaka up to Tokyo is direct path of the typhoon since the predicted path colored by red seems cover the areas. So, I think they would say 大阪から東京まで暴風域に入ります。 On the other hand, 本州から沖縄で強い雨が降る心配がある. as you say, I think at this time, they want to describe that it will rain a lot in most area from Okinawa to Honshu since the area is not in the strom area though but at least covered with the typhoon.